# accepts_nested_attributes_for: destroy all not included in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Is there a clean way to destroy all children NOT included in array of passed nested attributes?
Now I have to find difference between actual children and nested attributes array, and then set _destroy: true for each, but it looks ugly.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :consumed_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :consumed_products, allow_destroy: true

  def nested_attributes_destroy_difference(attrs)
    combined = attrs.reduce({}) {|h,pairs| pairs.each {|k,v| (h[k] ||= []) << v}; h}
    diff = consumed_products - consumed_products.where(combined)
    attrs + diff.map{|i| {id: i.id, _destroy: true} }
  end

end

class Api::V2::ReportsController < Api::V2::BaseController
  def update
    report = Report.find(params[:id])
    report_attributes = report_params

    if params[:consumed_products]
      report_attributes.merge!(consumed_products_attributes: report.nested_attributes_destroy_difference(consumed_products_attributes))
    end

    report.assign_attributes report_attributes
  end

  private 

  def consumed_products_attributes
    params[:consumed_products].map do |p|
      {product_id: p[:id], product_measure_id: p[:measure_id], quantity: p[:quantity]}
    end
  end

  def report_params
    #... 
  end

end
```

Comment: What happens when you add `allow_destroy: true` like this  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :consumed_products, allow_destroy: true`?

Comment: Yep, I forgot it in post. without `allow_destroy: true` there is no way to destroy child with `_destroy: true`, but to actually destroy any child you have to add `destroy: true` for every child you need to destroy, and to do so you need to find them beforehand

Comment: I thought `accepts_nested_attributes_for` called `collection=` which would do this automatically? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-objects

Comment: @japed yes, it would, but if I want to update some of the children? `report.consumed_products = params[:consumed_products].map{ |i| Report::ConsumedProduct.find_or_initialize_by(i) }` - something like this will create new records for each updated child and destroy the old one, it's ok sometimes, not always.